# Complex Cepstral Transform on Audio in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, wavelet, signal-analysis, transform

Hello I am trying to computer the Complex Cepstral Transform of an audio signal. I am using `wavread` to get an array of data type double precision. However, when I try to use `cceps` to do the Complex Cepstral Transform, I get the following error:

```
Error using cceps>chkinput (line 157)
The input signal X must be real.

Error in cceps (line 73)
chkinput(x);
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there another way to do this transform? Thank you!

Also, I tried computing this manually using the definition of the complex cepstral transform as follows:

```
C=ifft(ln(fft(f)))
```

where f is the array of double precision audio data. However, this returns the error: 
`Undefined function 'ln' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

Comment: The natural logarithm is called 'log' in Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural log in matlab is 'log(x)' and log to the base 10 is 'log10(x)'

More information on [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/log.html)